# Is morphologyEx supposed to use out of matrix elements as border pixels?

Tags: c++, opencv

This was run using OpenCV 4.0.1.  Not sure about prev versions.

The code below shows that OpenCV's dilation, and I think morphologyEx in general, doesn't return the same results when computed on a submatrix vs a clone of the same matrix. It seems to use out-of-submatrix values to compute the edge values of the result.

In short, v2in and v3in are equivalent but the v2in is made of a submatrix of v1 whereas v3in is a clone of that.  Yet, the dilation of the two gives different results where the dilation v2in seems to incorrectly use data, not in v2in taken from elements of v1in adjacent to v2in's data.

```
// dilation of a 1x7 "vector" works as expected.
Mat_<uchar> vin1 = (Mat_<uchar>(1, 7) << 0,0,0,1,0,0,0);
std::cout << "vin1:" << vin1 << std::endl;
Mat_<uchar> vout1;
morphologyEx(vin1, vout1, MORPH_DILATE, Mat::ones(1, 5, CV_8UC1));
std::cout << "vout1:" << vout1 << std::endl;

// Changing the edge values of v1in1.
Mat_<uchar> vin2;
vin1(0) = 255; vin1(6) = 128;
// creating v2 as a subset of v1 that doesn't include it edge elements (v1 elts 0 and 6)
vin2 = vin1.colRange(1, 6);
// printing the state of things.  Comfirming that v2 is in fact a sub-matrix of 1 that doesn't include the 
// edge (v1 elts 0 and 6) values of vin1
std::cout << "in1(0) = 255; vin1(6) = 128 modified vin1= " << vin1 << std::endl;
std::cout << "vin1.datastart= "  << std::hex << static_cast<const void*>(vin1.datastart) << std::endl;
std::cout << "vin2=vin1.colRange(1, 6), vin2=" << vin2 << std::endl;
std::cout << "vin2.datastart= " << std::hex << static_cast<const void*>(vin2.datastart) << std::endl;
std::cout << "vin2.data= " << std::hex << static_cast<void*>(vin2.data) << std::endl;
// dilation of v2, in vout2, uses the data not in v2, taken from v1 elts 0 and 6 yielding bad results.
Mat_<uchar> vout2;
morphologyEx(vin2, vout2, MORPH_DILATE, Mat::ones(1, 5, CV_8UC1));
std::cout << "Dilate of vin2=vin1.colRange(1, 6), vout2= " << vout2 << std::endl;
Mat_<uchar> vin3 = vin1.colRange(1, 6).clone();
// But doing the same dilation using a clone vs a submatrix gives a different, and correct, answer.
std::cout << "vin3=vin1.colRange(1, 6).clone(), vin3=" << vin3 << std::endl;
Mat_<uchar> vout3;
morphologyEx(vin3, vout3, MORPH_DILATE, Mat::ones(1, 5, CV_8UC1));
std::cout << "Dilate of vin3=vin1.colRange(1, 6).clone(), vout3" << vout3 << std::endl;
```

**Output:**

> vin1:[  0,   0,   0,   1,   0,   0,   0]
>
> vout1:[  0,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   0]
>
> in1(0) = 255; vin1(6) = 128 modified vin1= [255,   0,   0,   1,   0,   0, 128]
>
> vin1.datastart= 000001DC6A628FC0
>
> vin2=vin1.colRange(1, 6), vin2=[  0,   0,   1,   0,   0]
>
> vin2.datastart= 000001DC6A628FC0
>
> vin2.data= 000001DC6A628FC1
>
> Dilate of vin2=vin1.colRange(1, 6), vout2= [255, 255,   1, 128, 128]
>
> vin3=vin1.colRange(1, 6).clone(), vin3=[  0,   0,   1,   0,   0]
>
> Dilate of vin3=vin1.colRange(1, 6).clone(), vout3[  1,   1,   1,   1,   1]

Comment: Have you checked the `borderType` parameters of `morphologyEx()`? I think taking a look at the docs would answer your questions: https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga67493776e3ad1a3df63883829375201f. The `borderType` parameter is used in a number of places in OpenCV, and the `cv::BorderTypes` enum describes how each works with simple string examples: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga209f2f4869e304c82d07739337eae7c5

Comment: Thanks.  I hadn't noticed the BORDER_ISOLATED MUXable flag/option That being said, unless I'm missing it, neither that or the morphologyEx doc explains this as a default which I think is problematic in the context of the same doc giving the default border as BORDER_CONSTANT (which would, at least on the face of it, not be consistent.)